# How to sort a table via complicated rules

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have a table like this:

```
a-1/1    1.1
a-2/3    2.3
a-1/3    1.3
a-10/1   10.1
a-10/2   10.2
a-2/1    2.1
a-1/2    1.2
a-2/2    2.2
..
```

I need to sort it into something like this:

```
a-1/1    1.1
a-1/2    1.2
a-1/3    1.3
a-2/1    2.1
a-2/2    2.2
a-2/3    2.3
..
a-10/1   10.1
a-10/2   10.2
a-10/3   10.3
```

The tough things in this case:

1. I am sorting a table
2. I am sorting the table with a part, rather than the value itself, in the column.

Comment: [You can use a plugin](http://tablesorter.com/).

Comment: Thanks, I finally tried dataTables and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var data =
['a-1/1    1.1',
 'a-2/3    2.3',
 'a-1/3    1.3',
 'a-10/1   10.1',
 'a-10/2   10.2',
 'a-2/1    2.1',
 'a-1/2    1.2',
 'a-2/2    2.2'];

data.sort(function (f, s) {
    var one = parseFloat(f.split(/\s+/)[1]), two = parseFloat(s.split(/\s+/)[1]);
    return one === two ? 0 : one > two ? 1 : -1;
});

console.log(data);
```

**Output**

```
[ 'a-1/1    1.1',
  'a-1/2    1.2',
  'a-1/3    1.3',
  'a-2/1    2.1',
  'a-2/2    2.2',
  'a-2/3    2.3',
  'a-10/1   10.1',
  'a-10/2   10.2' ]
```